# Android how to get name of app used to share

Tags: java, android, android-intent, share

I'm using the following method to share an image with any app the user picks.

```
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("image/*");
    File imageFileToShare = new File(imagePath);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(imageFileToShare));

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
    }
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share with").addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
```

This works fine, but now I'm trying to get the name of the app picked by the user for sharing. Is there a (standard) way to do this?

Thanks for the attention.
Jose

Comment: you can create your own chooser dialog, but i don't think there's a way to get notified if the user actually completed the sharing process

Answer (score 6):

This is not supported prior to Android 6.0, when using the Android chooser. On Android 6.0+, you can use [`EXTRA_CHOOSER_REFINEMENT_INTENT_SENDER`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_CHOOSER_REFINEMENT_INTENT_SENDER) to provide an `IntentSender` that will be notified when the user makes a choice and what that choice is.

You are welcome to use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` to find out what activities support your `shareIntent` and create your own UI for the user to choose from. Then, since it is your own UI, you will find out what the user chose.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this code:

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");

getNameFromApp(packageManager);
```

And

```
public String getNameFromApp(PackageManager packageManager) {

    List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);

    int lastDot = 0;

    String name = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < resolveInfos.size(); i++) {

       // Extract the label, append it, and repackage it in a LabeledIntent
       ResolveInfo resolveInfo = resolveInfos.get(i);
            String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;

       lastDot= packageName.lastIndexOf(".");

       name = packageName.substring(lastDot + 1);
    }

    return name;
}
```

This code gets last app's name. But You can do it however you want to. Just do it!.